# How to get the right custom color for legend

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

Custom colours for doughnut chart is not showing in legend, rather legends take arbitrary colours. How can I make it pickup those custom colours?

```
app.controller("ExampleController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.pie = [
            {key: "Passed", y: 2},
            {key: "Failed", y: 3}
        ];

        var colorArray = ['red', 'green'];
        $scope.colorFunction = function() {
            return function(d, i) {
                return colorArray[i];
            };
        };
        ...x y functions ...
}]);
```

HTML

```
...
    <nvd3-pie-chart
            data="pie"
            id="donutLabelsOutsideExample"
            width="450"
            height="350"
            x="xFunction()"
            y="yFunction()"
            donut="true"
            showLabels="true"
            showLegend="true"
            donutLabelsOutside="true"
            labelType="percent"
            color="colorFunction()">
        <svg height="250"></svg>
    </nvd3-pie-chart>
...
```

[image: Legend screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives/blob/master/src/directives/nvd3Directives.js#L1153) for the pie chart contains an attribute for `legendcolor`, so you can try adding that attribute.

```
legendcolor="colorFunction()"
```

Why it works:

1. In the controller of `pieChart` there is a call to `checkElementID` which in turn calls `configureLegend`
2. `configureLegend` is found in [source code](https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives/blob/649f8c76a14196f96cacdd04a7e9fc03a7b28be3/src/directives/nvD3LegendConfiguration.js) and has the following code

`chart.legend.color(attrs.legendcolor === undefined ? nv.utils.defaultColor() : scope.legendcolor());`

`attrs.legendcolor` is pulled from your directive attribute.

Comment: @Bala added details for why (which are also missing in the duplicates of this Q)